# Teradata: how to divide a table by row number?

Tags: sql, teradata

How to divide a table in several parts by row number?
Condition might look like this:

```
create table part1 as
Select * from table
where row_number between 1 and 1000000

create table part2 as
Select * from table
where row_number between 1000001 and 2000000
```

thx

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `QUALIFY` clause. It would be something like this

```
Select * from table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) BETWEEN 1 and 1000000;

Select * from table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) BETWEEN 1000001 and 2000000;
```

You can create your tables with those queries. Consider that the `ORDER BY` option must be some combination that make the row unique in order to have consistent results.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() - is function in Teradata, should go with parentheses.